# Can only hear one application’s sound at a time

Tags: windows-7

When the sound is coming from multiple applications, I can hear only 1 of them, the others appear to be muted. For example, when I play music using VLC and also watch a video on YouTube or play a game, then I can hear only the music from VLC and nothing else. Except between tracks, when I hear the sound of the other app for 1-2 secs.

As far as I know, this is not the normal behavior of Windows 7, at least I did not experience anything similar on my old PC. Is there a way to fix this?

Note: I use the HDMI output of my video card (nvidia) and play audio on a LED TV, which serves as a second display too.

Meanwhile my new headphones arrived. They appear to mix the sounds of multiple apps properly, so I think the problem is something HDMI related. Maybe that output is differently configured or something like that, idk.